# Working out percentages from other percentages - no raw data

Tags: statistics

I'm having some difficulty trying to figure out how to come up with a way to solve my problem. I have the following information:

12% of men do X activity
26% of women do X activity
28% of 25-34 years olds do X activity

I want to find out what percentage of women aged 25-34 do the activity, but I'm not sure of how to do this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

If age and sex are **independent**, then you can multiply, first noting that $26\% = \frac{26}{100} = 0.26$ and $28\% =\frac{28}{100}= 0.28$

Then, $0.26 \times 0.28 = 0.0728 = 0.0728 \times 100\% = 7.28\%\,$ of women of age $25 - 34$ do activity $X.$

If age and sex are **not** independent, then you don't have enough information to answer the question.

Comment: Nice guidance -> =1